# -bash: vim: command not found

Tags: bash

I have been trying to install something in my bash_profile, which looked like this:

```
# Set architecture flags
export ARCHFLAGS="-arch x86_64"
# Ensure user-installed binaries take precedence
export PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH
# Load .bashrc if it exists
test -f ~/.bashrc && source ~/.bashrc
```

I was trying to add the Path to my pg_config file: /Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/Versions/9.6/bin

So my bash_profile looked like:

```
# Set architecture flags
export ARCHFLAGS="-arch x86_64"
# Ensure user-installed binaries take precedence
export PATH=/usr/local/bin:/Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/Versions/9.6/bin:$PATH
# Load .bashrc if it exists
test -f ~/.bashrc && source ~/.bashrc
```

When I tried to source the file i got:

> -bash: /usr/local/bin:/Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/Versions/9.6/bin:: No such file or directory

When I try to open the bash_profile I now get:

> -bash: vim: command not found

What have I done wrong?

**Additional info**

I have installed Python, PGAdmin4 and Django via Homebrew
I have downloaded Postgress.app also and was trying to install psycopg2, when it told me I had no pg_config. So I was trying to add the path to my bash_profile. Which I think is the right thing to do

Comment: is vim installed in your system ? `vim --version` is returning vim version ?

Comment: @sa77 vim is installed I use it all the time. It just stopped working

Comment: It looks like you've messed up something in setting your `PATH` (which is why bash can't find vim anymore). Can you post the exact `.bash_profile` you have now? I suspect there are typos in the `export PATH` line (e.g. additional spaces, `;` instead of `:`, etc).

Comment: From the first error message in your question I think that **a**) the new value of the `PATH` variable is taken as a command to execute which is not found **b**) the `::` at the end makes me think the previous value of `PATH` would be NULL (empty) **c**) the `PATH` variable might be assigned a incorrect value and so the `vi` is command cannot be found.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@melpomene and @Jdamian I think were right here. I had trouble trying to then find and open my bash_profile as I couldn't use the terminal to run:

`defaults write com.apple.finder AppleShowAllFiles YES`

Thankfully this answer helped though: https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/186378/70982

I navigated in finder to my ~/ folder and and ran 
<kbd>⌘ CMD</kbd>+<kbd>⇧ SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>.</kbd>

Opened in sublime and My path had was written as this:

`export PATH=/usr/local/bin:/Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/Versions/9.6/bin:
$PATH`

So I removed the carriage return so it all fits on one line and that seemed to help. I can now open Vim